# Installing TeX Live on a Synology NAS

Tags: texlive

Has anyone tried to install TeX Live on a Synology NAS? TeX Live 2012 runs smoothly on my Raspberry Pi but I can think of a scenario where having it run on my NAS could make some sense.

Comment: Uwe, do you use precompiled binaries for arm7 on Pi?  How fast are they?

Comment: They are part of the standard TeX Live. I'll try to create a speed test.

Comment: Note that you need to use the precompiled binary for luatex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have successfully installed LaTeX on my Synology DS1511+ by installing first ipkg and optware so that I have had a /OPT directory. Then I have used the Documentation on http://www.churchtool.org/fileadmin/user_upload/docs/latex_in_userspace.pdf but I have installed the files to /opt/texlive.

I have problems on installing the same package to a DS212j because there is a smaller Marvell Processor.

---

I have now found binaries on this page: http://tug.org/texlive/custom-bin.html
Over a hint in this forum: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-August/032204.html
Now I try that binaries for "older arm(v5) systems":
http://dl.home.lancelotsix.com/texlive/2012/armv5tel-unknown-linux-gnueabi.tar.bz2
I will post my result in this discussion later on.